# UWP how to distinguish input devices

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-iot-core-10

I'm looking for way to distinguish from where input came (from which device, e.g keyboard, barcode scanner, magnetic card scanner. Something like [this](http://I'm%20looking%20for%20way%20to%20distinguish%20from%20where%20input%20came%20(from%20which%20device,%20e.g%20keyboard,%20barcode%20scanner,%20magnetic%20card%20scanner).%20Unfortunately%20KeyEventArgs.DeviceId,%20KeyRoutedEventArgs.DeviceId,%20Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().GetCurrentKeyEventDeviceId()%20don't%20work.%20Everything%20I%20mentioned%20returns%20empty%20string.%20I%20was%20searching%20for%20other%20solution%20but%20couldn't%20find%20anything.)). I thought that will be a piece of cake because of DeviceId, but unfortunately `KeyEventArgs.DeviceId, KeyRoutedEventArgs.DeviceId, Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().GetCurrentKeyEventDeviceId()` don't work. Everything I mentioned returns empty string (maybe I'm missing something?). I was searching for other solution but couldn't find anything.

Comment: [DeviceId is not supported for all input devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.keyroutedeventargs.deviceid). And I can reproduce this issue on Windows 10 Desktop, so it seems not Windows IoT Core issue.

Answer (score 0):

UWP provides support for identifying the input devices available (pointer, touch, mouse, and keyboard) and retrieving information about those devices.Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/identify-input-devices). But it does not support for getting the device information when the event handled.

Comment: Yes, I have seen this. But unfortunately I need to identify input device when the event is handled. To be specific,  I have to prevent user from typing in his ID while he has to use magnetic card scanner. I have to force him on this.

Comment: Do you think prevent the key event when typing in his ID is a workaround? When got the input from magnetic card scanner, a different event would be handled.

Comment: Yes, it would work, but how can I handle input from magnetic card scanner in a different way than key event? Magnetic card scanner is recognized like keyboard device, so the same event is fired. Or maybe there is a way to attach custom event to specific device?